# Parse and query SOAP in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, soap, xml-namespaces, mm7

I am trying to parse a heavily namespaced SOAP message (source can be found also [here](http://tinyurl.com/n3av6k)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Header>
  <ns1:TransactionID soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:ns1="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2">0a00f556419041c08d8479fbaad02a3c</ns1:TransactionID>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <SubmitRsp xmlns="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2">
   <MM7Version>5.3.0</MM7Version>
   <Status>
    <StatusCode xsi:type="ns2:responseStatusType_StatusCode" xmlns:ns2="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2" xmlns="">1000</StatusCode>
    <StatusText xsi:type="ns3:statusTextType" xmlns:ns3="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2" xmlns="">Success</StatusText>
   </Status>
   <MessageID>B08CF7B847DAD89C752334BDEBB69B5B</MessageID>
  </SubmitRsp>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Just for the context, this is a response of *MM7 Submit* message.

How can I get the following values:

TransactionID, StatusCode, StatusText, MessageID

I tried Linq-Xml but no luck when the query includes a value like "soapenv:Body".

Comment: I'm curious. Rather than parse the message, why not use a Service Reference?

Comment: Use the "Add Service Reference" command to create a service reference to the service returning this data. Then you can call it like a method and process the elements like classes with properties.

Comment: I'm aware of this option, but the service does not provide wsdl or disco.

Comment: Thanks for posting the XML. I poked around on the www.3gpp.org site. I would not have believed any organization could say the following in 2009: "This reference point shall be based on SOAP 1.1 [68] and SOAP messages with attachments [69] using an HTTP transport layer. *Future releases* **may** update this protocol decision to use a *standardized* version of SOAP and support additional transport layer implementations." This may be the first time I've seen an org deliberately use non-standard SOAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to build an `XName` with a namespace you need to build it from an `XNamespace` plus a string, e.g.

```
XNamespace soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
XName body = soapenv + "Body";
```

Then when you use the `XName` "`body`" with Linq-to-XML it will match the `<soapenv:Body>` element in your document.

You can do similar things to allow building the names of other elements with namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

There's an even simpler way. You can simply specify the namespace inline using {} notation:

```
var soap = XElement.Load(soapPath);
var transactionID = 
        from e in soap.Descendants("{http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2}TransactionID")
        select e.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use XmlDocument (for reading the XML) and XmlNamespaceManager (for retreiving the namespace data) and using XPath queries from those objects.